# AngularJS : Issue passing data to a new browser window on Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass some objects to a new browser window. I followed the suggestion from [AngularJS: open a new browser window, yet still retain scope and controller, and services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519113/angularjs-open-a-new-browser-window-yet-still-retain-scope-and-controller-and)

It works on Chrome, but doesn't on IE. My shared objects are always *undefined* on IE. Any suggestions?

Code for simplified version of what I am trying to do

My parent html

```
<html ng-app="SampleAngularApp">   

<body>
 <div ng-controller="popupCtrl">
        <my-popup foo="foo" abc="abc">Open Popup from here</my-popup>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My parent JS

```
var SampleAngularApp = angular.module('SampleAngularApp', []);

    var popupCtrl = function ($scope) {

        $scope.foo = { baz: 'qux' };
        $scope.abc = "12345";
    };

SampleAngularApp.directive('myPopup', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            foo: '=',
            abc: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.css({ 'cursor': 'pointer' });
            elem.bind('click', function () {

            var popWdw = $window.open("popupWindow.html", "popupWindow", "width=500,height=500,left=100,top=100,location=no");

            popWdw.abc = scope.abc;
            popWdw.foo = JSON.stringify(scope.foo);

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

My popup html

```
<html ng-app="PopupApp">

<body ng-controller="childCtrl">

</body>
</html>
```

My popup JS

```
var PopupApp = angular.module('PopupApp', []);

var childCtrl = function ($scope) {   

    alert(window.foo);

};

PopupApp.controller(childCtrl);
```

Comment: Think you need to look into the problem from a JavaScript perspective first then worry about applying it to Angular.  The underlying issue you're encountering sounds like it's just a problem with the JS itself, without using angular test to see if in a simple case you can pass any information from one window to another. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window

Comment: @ shaunhusain : As you said the problem could be with the JS itself, but I am unable to figure it out. When I try with just 2 html pages and no angular, everything just works fine. Can you please look at my above code and let me know what I am missing. Though I didn't post references, they are all properly referenced in my solution as it works on Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps its a timing issue. Try using $timeout or add a button with an ng-click handler to the pop up app, so you can query the value of `window.foo`. Perhaps `window.foo` gets populated after your pop up app's controller is initialized. The link that shaunhusain added refers to using the `window.opener` property (from the popup). You could try the opposite and set `window.foo` in the parent app and then use `window.opener.foo` to access the value from the pop up...

Comment: Thanks shaunhusain and SunilD. Setting the parent property and using the window.opener worked. I am still unsure why it doesn't work the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

Per shaunhusain and Sunil D's suggestions, I have changed my code as below and it works

My parent JS

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.css({ 'cursor': 'pointer' });
            elem.bind('click', function () {

            $window.abc = scope.abc;
            $window.foo = JSON.stringify(scope.foo);

            var popWdw = $window.open("popupWindow.html", "popupWindow", "width=500,height=500,left=100,top=100,location=no");            

            });
        }
```

My popup JS

```
var childCtrl = function ($scope) {   

    alert(window.opener.foo);

};
```

Comment: The above solution works can i know how to take back the value from child to parent here's my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659514/how-to-exchange-a-value-from-pop-up-to-parent-window-in-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment38229609_24659514