# How to exchange a value from pop-up to parent window in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a scenario where I need to exchange the data dynamically (**From PARENT To CHILD** and **Reversal** (***PARENT to CHILD***) ). I referred from couple of links and it helped me to pass the data from PARENT to CHILD, **however From CHILD to PARENT didn't**.

Below i have the source code of Parent to Child (Html as well as the controller). Could somebody help me how to take the data back again.

**Parent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="parentWindowApp">
    <head>
        <title>Parent Window</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <script src="js/lib/angular-1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/controllers/parentWindowController.js"></script>
        <link href="js/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="parentWindowController">

        <div class="container">

            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="iptext.text" placeholder="I/P Value &AMP; Click Link"/>
            <a id="popupSymImg" tabindex="-1" ng-click="openChildWindow();"> Call Child Window </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**parentWindowController.js**

```
var parentWindow = angular.module('parentWindowApp',[]);

parentWindow.controller('parentWindowController', function ($scope,$window) {

   //$scope.shareData = "Parent Value from Parent Window";

   alert('Controller Loaded...');

   $scope.iptext = { text: ''};

   $scope.openChildWindow = function(){

       //$window.childWindowValue = angular.toJson(value);
       $window.childWindowValue =  angular.toJson($scope.iptext);
       alert("Before Open : "+$window.childWindowValue);

       $window.open('ChildWindow.html', 300,200);

       //alert("After Open  : "+$window.childWindowValue);

   };

 });
```

**ChildWindow.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html ng-app="childWindowApp">
     <head>
         <title>Child Window</title>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <meta name="description" content="">
         <meta name="author" content="">
         <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/lib/angular-1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/lib/controllers/childWindowController.js"></script>
         <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="childWindowController">

         <div class="container">

             <table>
                 <tr ng-repeat='shareData in shareDatas'>
                     <td >
                         <input ng-model='shareData.title' class="form-control" size="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="Item Name"
 required> 
                         <a id="popupSymImg" tabindex="-1" ng-click="closeChildWindow(shareData.title);"> Close Child Window </a>
                     </td>    
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </div>
   </body> </html>
```

**childWindowController.js**

```
var childWindow = angular.module('childWindowApp',[]);


childWindow.controller('childWindowController', function ($scope,$window) {

   //$scope.shareData = "Parent Value from Parent Window";

   alert("Value from parent :"+angular.toJson($window.opener.childWindowValue));

   $scope.parentValue = $window.opener.childWindowValue;

     $scope.shareDatas = [
                        {title: 'Item 1'},
                        {title: 'Item 2'},
                        {title: 'Item 3'},
                        {title: 'Item 4'},
                        {title: 'Item 5'},
                        {title: 'Item 6'},
                        {title: 'Item 7'}
                    ];

   $scope.closeChildWindow = function(value){


       //alert('In Opener :: '+$window.opener.childWindowValue);

       //alert('Child Window :: '+$scope.parentValue);

       alert('Value on Click :: '+value);

       $window.childWindowValue = value;

       alert('Current in Window Properties : '+$window.childWindowValue);

       //$window.close();

   };  


 });
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: use postMessage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_postMessage

Comment: Does the new "window" actually need to be a new browser window, or could you use a modal dialog within the same Angular app?  If so, this is easy to do with UI Bootstrap. The $modal service will return a promise when opened, and your child window can resolve the promise to pass a value back to the parent.

Comment: @charlietfl Mozila API can't be used since my application used only in IE

Comment: @cliff.meyers Can i know some example with UI Bootstrap? and If I use the bootstrap it would change the entire application UI will it be possible not change. Kindly let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @Arun `postMessage` has nothing to do with Mozilla, the MDN docs just happen to be the best browser documentation available

Comment: @Arun you should just be able to pull in the modal and the CSS for the modal itself. You shouldn't need to pull in all the Bootstrap CSS.  You could also build your own modal, it's really just a DOM element that is positioned relatively or absolutely on the screen.

Comment: I have used showModalDialog to exchange the data between Parent and Child and it is working fine. This link gives the explanation on showModalDialog http://itwebtutorials.net/JavaScript/JS07/jsdhtml07-05.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `showModalDialog` to exchange the data between Parent and Child and it is working fine.

See also [showModalDialog tutorial](http://itwebtutorials.net/JavaScript/JS07/jsdhtml07-05.php).