# Pass data from caller to popup window on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup

I'm trying to pass the scope among other values to the child window. Currently, it works as expected on Chrome, but in internet explorer doesn't. Is there a way around ?

```
var  templateUrl = "/someviewpage";

  var wOptions$ = 'menubar=no, toolbar=no, location=0, status=no, 
  resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=175,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=800,height =' + 
  window.innerHeight;

  var fname$ = 'mike',lname$ = 'jackson';  
   var dataDto$ = {
                fname: fname$,
                lname: lname$,
                parentScope: $scope
            };
  var openUploadWindow$ = $window.open(templateUrl, 'coolpopup', wOptions$);

  openUploadWindow$.data = dataDto$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Question had been asked and answered here: [angularjs-issue-passing-data-to-a-new-browser-window-on-internet-explorer](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921262/angularjs-issue-passing-data-to-a-new-browser-window-on-internet-explorer)

Final code looks like this:

```
var  templateUrl = "/someviewpage";

  var wOptions$ = 'menubar=no, toolbar=no, location=0, status=no, 
  resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=175,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=800,height =' + 
  window.innerHeight;

  var fname$ = 'mike',lname$ = 'jackson';  
   var dataDto$ = {
                fname: fname$,
                lname: lname$,
                parentScope: $scope
            };

   $window.data = dataDto$;
  var openUploadWindow$ = $window.open(templateUrl, 'coolpopup', wOptions$);
```

Inside popup window js:

```
console.log(window.opener.data);
```