# Angularjs. Open content in new tab

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

I've read similar questions/answers on SO, but can't resolve my problem.
Here is the setup:
**index.html**

```
<li ng-repeat="a in article">
   <a ng-click="articleDetails(a.id)">
     {{a.title_en}}
   </a>
</li>
```

**js file**

```
angular.module('myApp.article', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/article/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'article/article.html',
            controller: 'ArticleDetailCtrl'
        });
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])        
    .controller('ArticleDetailCtrl', ['$http', '$routeParams', '$scope', '$window', '$location',
        function ($http, $routeParams, $scope, $window, $location) {
           $scope.params = 'blabla';
        }])
```

**article.html**

```
<div>{{params}}</div>
```

**Question:** When I click the link in index.html new tab is opened as expected with correct url, however, instead of article details I get **Not found** on the webpage. What might be a problem?

**EDIT 1**: Function articleDetail is defined as follows in another controller that is used in index.html:

```
$scope.articleDetails = function (id) {
                $scope.id = id;
                $scope.window = $window.open('article/' + id, '_blank');
            }
```

Comment: try using `$location.path` instead of `$window`

Comment: I would like to open content in a new tab, that's why I use $window.

Comment: `$window.open` will open the URL in a new tab which will not have the `$scope` of your angular application since the `$scope` is tied only to the window in which ng-app is initialized. That is why you are getting Not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot retain the scope of your Angular application in another window. Hence calling `$window.open` will open a new window which does not have your original `$scope`.

The scope is tied only to the window in which the `ngApp` is initialized.

In order to overcome this, you can use the `LocalStorage` of your browser.

**EDIT:** Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519113/angularjs-open-a-new-browser-window-yet-still-retain-scope-and-controller-and)