# Open button in new window/tab angular

Tags: angularjs, button

I would like to enable "Open in new window / tab" on button. Frankly, I tried many ways, and unluckily it doesn't work.

Here is my button:

```
<button class="button no-margin-bottom" data-ng-click="vm.navigateToProject(project)"
data-sd-secured
data-sd-secured-contextual="project.permissions.canViewProjectDetails"
data-translate>PROJECTS.VIEW</button>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Then list methods you are tried

Comment: I tried to change button on a. Or put the button between a tags (<a herf="something"> <button> .... </button> </a>) Unluckily it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it that you want to achieve with the new window / tab? To run your angular application in parallel, or just to have an external link?

If you want to run it in parallel, then there will be a few issues that you'll come across concerning the shared data. You can read more in this post:
[AngularJS: open a new browser window, yet still retain scope and controller, and services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519113/angularjs-open-a-new-browser-window-yet-still-retain-scope-and-controller-and)

But if you just want an option to open a new tab, then that can be done fairly easily:
Simplest - html solution: `<a href="#" target="_blank">link/button</a>`

or by using javascript alone: `window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');`
Here you can see more about that approach [How to open a URL in a new Tab using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851782/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Or eventually implementing it in angular [Open links in new window using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099784/open-links-in-new-window-using-angularjs)