# Configure angular ui-router to use absolute URLs by default

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My angular app with ui-router is running inside a page at `/content/page.html`. The page also has a

```
<base href="/somewhere">
```

tag in the head.

Due to the base tag I end up with incorrect URLs pointing to `/somewhere#/section1` instead of `/content/page.html#/section1`

I'm unable to remove this base tag since I'm just a small part of a large site. Is there a way to make ui-router generate absolute URLs by default? I've noticed that `ui-sref-opts="{absolute: true}"` can do this, but it generates the link using the base tag. Is there a way to make ui-router always create absolute URLs using window.location.pathname?

edit: I've created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qmia2g1EqjGMKVioYVx6?p=preview) that demonstrates the problem.

Regards, Markus

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved it by using an angular decorator and overriding the behaviour of the $urlRouter 'href' function.

Comment: @Markus please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace `<base href="/somewhere">` by `<base href="/">` and add a link with your url in your config route in app.js.

html:

```
<base href='/'>
<a ui-sref="nameOfTheRoute">Link</a>
```

in app.js add the route:

```
$stateProvider.state('nameOfTheRoute',{url:'/', templateUrl:'Content/page.html'})
```

PS: I tried this on my application with another base href and it's works so you can try without change base url tag.

html:

```
<base href='/somewhere'>
<a ui-sref="nameOfTheRoute">Link</a>
```

in app.js add the route:

```
$stateProvider.state('nameOfTheRoute',{url:'/somewhere', templateUrl:'Content/page.html'})
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thx. It seems it would not be possible for users to right click the link and open it in a new tab, wouldn't it? The angular app and ui-router are not available at '/somewhere'.  I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Hi, have you add the dependancy in your index to use ui router in your       app.js ? The right click is mandatory ? For me, I use Modal bootstrap to open my view in new  window. But I don't know if this can correspond with yours expectations.

Comment: What technology you use for your application ?

Comment: To open a new tab look this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519113/angularjs-open-a-new-browser-window-yet-still-retain-scope-and-controller-and . To the pop menu you can look with bootstrop I think.

Comment: I just want to make sure the site has a normal website behavior. That means that links can be opened in new tabs and can be bookmarked. I've created a plunker to demonstate the problem (see above). I don't think the solution you mentioned would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer help you more than my previous answers ^^. I tested your  plunker and now the default route works. I hope this is what you search

[new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ml5vaX7TBxDOClzWmwXD?p=preview)

```
Keep me informed.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The links in this plunker still point to http://run.plnkr.co/somewher/route2 though. Tested with Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I changed the route to verify if the redirect works. So, your problem is resolved ?

Comment: Why the link is wrong ? Your route contain  somewhere but you can anyway redirect to your page html in /content/page.html or I realy don't understood your problem. Can you explain more clearly your problem in this case.

Comment: The link points to http://run.plnkr.co/somewher/route1. This is wrong. It should be http://run.plnkr.co/route1.

Comment: And Why you can't change <base href="/somewhere">  for <base href="/">. Because, I tried it and when the href is equal to "/" the link is good (http://run.plnkr.co/route1)