# angular js scope value not updated in another window

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have developed one sample page using angular js.

Just i add comments in textbox and submit, I will add the values in scope variable and display the content in same page using ng repeater, It's working fine but if i open the same page in another window, the old results only displayed,Current scope variable not updated any idea?

Comment: Show your code here. we can't help until you don't show code

Comment: Angulr js works only in one window. Opening a new window will create a new angular app. So it will not retain the values..

Comment: it's like discussion window....different user logged-in and post his comment...the new message will show to another logged-in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retain the scope of your Angular application in another window. The scope is tied only to the window in which the `ngApp` is initialized.

In order to overcome this, you can use the `LocalStorage` of your browser.

**EDIT:** Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519113/angularjs-open-a-new-browser-window-yet-still-retain-scope-and-controller-and)

But in your case, you will have to use a DB or such which will need a backend server too. The MEAN stack is a very nice stack to work on with Angular as the front with Expressjs to connect with Nodejs as the backend along with MongoDB