# Passing a variable using window angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have two angularjs applications what i want is to pass a variable from `app1` to `app2`.

So I tried using window popup to pass the variable but its giving me undefined value.

**app1**

```
vm.test = test;
function test() {
  var popupWindow = window.open('http://localhost:4000');
  popupWindow.mySharedData = 'testdakjasdhasgdhasdghasgd';
}
```

**app2**

```
$interval(callAtInterval, 1000);

function callAtInterval() {
  // var oldata;
  console.log(window.mySharedData); // giving me undefined value
}
```

Comment: so there is no opportunity to store this data in a database of some sort?  and you can not use a shared angular service?

Comment: @BryanDellinger I also put that into consideration. But when i saw this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519113/angularjs-open-a-new-browser-window-yet-still-retain-scope-and-controller-and) it show that i can pass a variable to another application by using **window.open**

Comment: You can pass the data as query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In you first controller do like this inside the test function.

```
     window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

Then retrieve that piece of information via this command if it is not a sensitive data.

```
    window.localStorage.getItem(key)
```